# How to deal with non destroyable GCP elements in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm creating my GCP infra using terraform. It includes BigQuery Datasets, Cloud Storage Buckets and also Task Queues and App Engine.

The problem is that App Engine and Task Queue have some particular behaviour:

- AppEngine can not be deleted once created (We would need to delete the project to able to get rid of it)
- Task Queue, if we create a queue named 'default' on it, it can not be deleted as well.

This is creating some problems for me since, I'm not being able to **terraform destroy** the resources I've created so I can clean my environment.

What is the suggested workaround this kind of issues?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is an underlying dependency that the cloudprovider creates or one has created inadvertingly, which is not being managed by the terraform workspace. In other cases it is managed by other workspaces because the account or resource is being shared between other resources.

So when one is struggling to delete certain resources it's sometimes  easier to go to the console and remove the resource manually on the console when this sort of trouble comes about. Terraform will synchronize its state afterwards when you run your next terraform destroy or plan .

An example of these hidden dependencies (in aws) is when you try to delete a vpc but theres still an eni attached to the vpc or when trying to remove a s3 bucket that has data in it .

In the case of the vpc , you'd have to delete the eni first and then only will the vpc get removed. Similarly , with the s3 bucket , one would have to empty the bucket (essentialy delete all of the data that had been stored in it) before you can remove the bucket. Terraform will simply fail or hang because it cant remove those dependencies as they were not managed by the terraform configuration.

If you ever need to delete a single/targeted resource , commenting out the resource and its respective dependencies should do the trick .

Hope this was useful for you .

Answer (score 1):

You might want add a destroy only provisioner: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#destroy-time-provisioners

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    on_failure = continue
    command = "echo 'Destroy-time provisioner'"
  }
  # properties
  
}
```

Execute a command or a list of commands to delete the resources that prevent the destroy from working such as the project.